# Pyomo abstract model - Cost per unit in transportation a function of quantity shipped

Tags: python-3.x, nonlinear-optimization, pyomo

My problem is an extension of transportation problem. The decision variable is  the quantity required to move from one warehouse to another. There are three costs involved : inbound, outbound and line haul cost. My objective function is to reduce the overall cost. However, the inbound costs per unit depends on the quantity that is shipped from one warehouse to another and the relationship is in the form of a step function.

Sample rows for inbound cost per unit csv file. It has two columns:
**Quantity** and **inbound Cost per unit**.
Row 1: 5 units    and          $10, 
Row 2: 10 units   and          $30

If the units shipped is less than 5 units, then the cost is $10, where as cost is $30 if the units shipped is greater then 5 and less than 10 units

The format for outbound and line haul cost is similar to the format of inbound cost. I am trying to build an abstract model in pyomo. I am not sure how to code the objective function when the cost per unit varies with the quantity (decision variable) in the form of step function. If the costs per unit were static , it would have been a simple multiplication of quantity and unit cost.

```
def inbound_cost(qty):
    for index, row in inbound_cost.iterrows():
        if(value(qty)<=row["Quantity"]):
            return(row["inbound Cost per unit"])


def objective_rule(model):
    return sum(model.qty[SKU,Source,Destination]*inbound_cost(model.qty[SKU,Source,Destination]) for SKU in model.SKU for Source in model.Source for Destination in model.Destination)
model.objectiveFunc = Objective(rule = objective_rule, sense=minimize)
```

Comment: So what have you tried so far?

Comment: I created two  functions. One for objective function and other for inbound costs. The objective function calls the inbound function for getting the cost. The inbound function iterates through the rows to figure out a cost/unit value basis the quantity shipped. However, it is somehow always picking up the first value. I can see that when the objective function is displayed when I print it using model.instance

Comment: You don't want to do an **if** on a decision variable. These type of things are explicitly modeled as piecewise linear functions. The problem looks to be convex (increasing marginal cost) so you don't need binary or SOS2 variables). Advice: first write down the mathematical model before you start coding.

Comment: Also the model depends on the details. If 6 units are shipped, is the total cost 5 * $10 + 1 * $30 or 6 * $30. The first cost curve is continuous, the second one is not.

Comment: The cost is 6* $30. How can we model it through linear functions without an If condition on a decision variable for this use case ?

Comment: **Problem statement**
Quantity – q ; Inbound cost – c;
 **Inbound cost per unit function** : c = $5 if 0 < q < 2 ; c = $10 if 2<= q < 10.
 Objective function:Minimize c*q and Decision variable : q

@ErwinKalvelagen I tried doing the following. Need your help to understand if this works and how can it be easily modeled in pyomo. Added two binary variables a,b and constraint their values.
step 1:Add new dummy decision variable a, b. Total decision variables : a,b, q
step 2:Objective function:Minimize q*[5a+10b]
step 3:Constraints:a>=0; a<=1; b>=0; b<=1; a+b=1; q>0; aq<2; 2a+bq>=2; bq<5

Comment: You make it nonlinear. There are better, standard linear formulations for this.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to attack this:

- Pyomo has built-in facilities for pwl (piecewise linear) functions in linear models. Please check the Pyomo documentation which explains this in detail.
- This can be modeled with implications (indicator constraints). In Pyomo you can use disjunctions. Please read the Pyomo documentation for more information.
- This can be modeled with SOS1 variables. See the Pyomo documentation how to use these.
- This can be modeled with binary variables. Actually in quite a few different ways.

Here is one example how this can be modeled **linearly** using a single binary variable. Let δ ∈ {0,1} (i.e. a binary variable). Then we can formulate:

```
 cost ≥ 5 x
 cost ≥ 10 x −  10 U (1-δ)  
 x ≤ 2 + δ U
 0 ≤ x ≤ U
```

Here U is an upperbound on x.